# Pandoc: Using stylesheet causes unwanted numbers in generated table of contents

Tags: pandoc

When I create an ePub file with pandoc for export to Kindle MOBI
format, naming a style sheet on the command line causes each chapter in the table of contents to be preceded by a number. Given files 1.md and 2.md with h1 headers Chapter 1 and Chapter 2, the generated TOC looks like this,
but only if you include a style sheet using `--epub-stylesheet`:

```
1. Chapter 1
2. Chapter 2
```

Command line that causes the problem:

```
$ pandoc --table-of-contents --epub-stylesheet=epub.css *.md title.yaml -o foo.epub
```

If I do the same thing without specifying a style sheet, it doesn't happen:

```
$  pandoc  --table-of-contents  *.md title.yaml -o foo.epub
```

The generated table of contents then looks like this, which is what I want:

```
Chapter 1
Chapter 2
```

It doesn't matter what the contents of the style sheet are. It happens even when it is completely empty.

**Contents of file `1.md`:**

```
# Chapter 1 

hello, world.
```

**Contents of file `2.md`:**

```
# Chapter 2

Oh, I love Chapter 2!
```

**Contents of file `epub.css`:**

```
/* Empty */
```

**Contents of file `title.yaml`:**

```
---
title:  'My book'
author: 'Author name'
rights: © 2017 by Author 
lang: en-US
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `--epub-stylesheet` you provide your own CSS stylesheet instead of the default one. You'll have to copy the styles you want to keep fron the [pandoc's default epub.css](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/data/epub.css), namely:

```
ol.toc { padding: 0; margin-left: 1em; }
ol.toc li { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: Fantastic! I somehow didn't know about the existence of epub.css. My life has definitely changed for the better, [mb21][1]! Thank you very much.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/users/214446/mb21